# C# tag in Data-Explorer links wrong

Tags: bug, data-explorer, special-characters

When running [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) my top votes is C#. I click on the link provided to the tag (which I'm assuming the system is handling converting the tags to links as I dont' see anywhere in the query doing it)and it takes me to questions tagged with `C` because # is a special character.

Is this due to something that I'm missing in the query or is this an issue with the data-explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoops, yeah, the tag name should be encoded. [And now it will be](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/45), pending a pull and redeploy. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! This has just been deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `TagName` feature needs to URLencode the tag name.

Comment: Would that be with `%23`?

Comment: That makes sense: the URL I get taken to is `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c#`, but the actual C# tag's URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23`. Naturally the # in the first doesn't get sent to the server as it's the fragment identifier!